# Google Maps API v.3 can't add marker when clicking a spot on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular6

I'm using addEventListener to add new Marker to Google Maps using angular version 6.
  I get everything needed **but** the actual Marker icon, it does not show on the map, why?

Here is a link to a working example on developers.google.com
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/info-windows-to-db

```
private isMapInitialized = false;
private map: any;


// Here everything statrs
ngOnInit() {
    this.openMapPanel();
}   


// Here I get the map and everything works great!
openMapPanel() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (!this.isMapInitialized) {
            this.initMap();

            this.isMapInitialized = true;
        }
    }, 300);
}


initMap() {
    var california = {lat: 37.4419, lng: -122.1419};
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: california,
        zoom: 13
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {
        this.placeNewMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}


placeNewMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: this.map
        });
    });
}
```

do I miss something?

Comment: can i see your complete script? i think you are missing something.

Comment: I edited the code, everything is there..

Comment: Are you able to see the map?

Comment: yes i can sure see it and when I click i get LatLng correctly in chrome console

Comment: Ok, second is i don't think this is a run able code, as openMapPanel event trigger is unknown to me.!!

Comment: For now, i can only suggest that there is something wrong with settimeOut event.

Comment: Ajay, of course, look now at the top of my code, edited again..

Comment: I think i got it.

Comment: please share it with me.. what do you think is the problem. you can be sure that is has nothing to do with settimeout.

Comment: placeNewMarker is user event based where user clicks on location, but you are calling on auto based - which will be giving error of course as the placeNewMarker don't know about the locations. Solution is if you pass locations as params to this method then it can be done.!

Comment: Try to pass gps lat long locations as a param to this method. you wiil see the marker.

Comment: let me know the status?

Comment: tried that, not working :( the thing is that i don't have lat and lng till I click the map - there must be another way..

Comment: comment this line //this.placeNewMarker(); and then run and click on map.

Comment: You are including a character literal in your `LatLng` creation. The constructor does not take character literals, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/coordinates#LatLng). You should try changing to the following: `var position = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng());`

Comment: tried that also and still not working, anyone can post a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It was so simple.. all I needed to do is change that line of code.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {
    this.placeMarker(event.latLan);
}
```

to

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {
        this.placeMarker(event.latLan);
});
```

and of course add the function

```
placeNewMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: this.map
    });
});
```

I hope it will help someone someday :-)